# Configure linux asterisk for inbound calls

Tags: linux, centos, asterisk

Would anyone please help me figuring this out:

I have configured Asterisk in Linux CentOS 5. I can make outbound calls from my sip phone in windows machine using asterisk server.

But I need to receive incoming calls. My ISP provided me 4 information. Username, Password, domain name & DID number. I understand I need to do something in sip.conf & extension.conf file. I think I need to modify this line:

register => 7777:123456@205.4.97.11:5060/88899
where 7777 is the username, 123456 is the password, 205.4.97.11 is the domain name & 88899 is the DID number.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Such question fully described in any asterisk book

This link can help you

http://www.asteriskdocs.org/